# Sending information to ubidots only if the condition are met

Tags: android

[The Image shows the dashboard of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0C2O.png)

```
package com.example.leeyueloong.proximityapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.estimote.mustard.rx_goodness.rx_requirements_wizard.Requirement;
import com.estimote.mustard.rx_goodness.rx_requirements_wizard.RequirementsWizardFactory;
import com.estimote.proximity_sdk.proximity.EstimoteCloudCredentials;
import com.estimote.proximity_sdk.proximity.ProximityContext;
import com.estimote.proximity_sdk.proximity.ProximityObserver;
import com.estimote.proximity_sdk.proximity.ProximityObserverBuilder;
import com.estimote.proximity_sdk.proximity.ProximityZone;
import com.ubidots.ApiClient;
import com.ubidots.Variable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import kotlin.Unit;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProximityObserver proximityObserver;
private int send;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EstimoteCloudCredentials cloudCredentials =
            new EstimoteCloudCredentials("tan-kok-hui-s-proximity-fo-07q", "d18623351c273ce3e09ffcc1f6201861");
    // 2. Create the Proximity Observer
    this.proximityObserver =
            new ProximityObserverBuilder(getApplicationContext(), cloudCredentials)
                    .withOnErrorAction(new Function1<Throwable, Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke(Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.e("app", "proximity observer error: " + throwable);
                            return null;
                        }
                    })

                    .withLowLatencyPowerMode()
                    .build();


    // add this below:

    ProximityZone zone = this.proximityObserver.zoneBuilder()

            .forTag("desks")
            .inNearRange()
            .withOnEnterAction(new Function1<ProximityContext, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(ProximityContext context) {
                    String deskOwner = context.getAttachments().get("desk-owner");
                    Log.d("app", "Welcome to " + deskOwner + "'s desk");
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .withOnExitAction(new Function1<ProximityContext, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(ProximityContext context) {
                    return null;
                }


            })

            .withOnChangeAction(new Function1<List<? extends ProximityContext>, Unit>() {

                @Override
                public Unit invoke(List<? extends ProximityContext> contexts) {

                    List<String> deskOwners = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ProximityContext context : contexts) {

                        deskOwners.add(context.getAttachments().get("desk-owner"));
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < deskOwners.size(); i++) {

                        if (deskOwners.get(i).contains("Peter")) {
                            send = 1;
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alert:Unauthorized Zone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending information to ubidots..........", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (deskOwners.get(i).contains("Alex")) {
                            send = 0;
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Device has entered this range", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else if (deskOwners.get(i).contains("Paul"))
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    Log.d("app", "In range of desks: " + deskOwners);
                    return null;
                }


            })
            .create();

    this.proximityObserver.addProximityZone(zone);
    ProximityZone innerZone = this.proximityObserver.zoneBuilder()
            .forTag("treasure")
            .inCustomRange(3.0)
            .create();

    ProximityZone outerZone = this.proximityObserver.zoneBuilder()
            .forTag("treasure")
            .inCustomRange(9.0)
            .create();

    RequirementsWizardFactory
            .createEstimoteRequirementsWizard()
            .fulfillRequirements(MainActivity.this,
                    // onRequirementsFulfilled
                    new Function0<Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke() {
                            Log.d("app", "requirements fulfilled");
                            proximityObserver.start();
                            return null;
                        }
                    },
                    // onRequirementsMissing
                    new Function1<List<? extends Requirement>, Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke(List<? extends Requirement> requirements) {
                            Log.e("app", "requirements missing: " + requirements);
                            return null;
                        }
                    },
                    // onError
                    new Function1<Throwable, Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke(Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.e("app", "requirements error: " + throwable);
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
}
private BroadcastReceiver mBatteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (send == 1 || send == 0) {
            new ApiUbidots().execute(send);
        }


    }
};
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
            registerReceiver(mBatteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        }
```

// Stop the BroadcastReceiver

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(mBatteryReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

// In Charge of sending variable to ubidots

```
    public class ApiUbidots extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
        private final String API_KEY = "A1E-0109ebb46b4990a4ed82f74d2912a9e6b481";
        private final String VARIABLE_ID = "5b62ab7ac03f97418ba1c28e";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
            Variable batteryLevel = apiClient.getVariable(VARIABLE_ID);

            batteryLevel.saveValue(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is i am able to sending the data to the ubidots however i want to make it so that only if the condition has met, it will then send to the cloud. Other than that, it would not have send any data to the cloud.

Comment: I suspect it would be the Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED as it send continuously no matter what happens.